# How to collect values for all the keys from a Dictionary<string,object> in a List

Tags: c#, list, csv, dictionary, collections

I have a `Dictionary<string, Data>` collection.

My Data class is has multiple members.

```
public class Data
{
public string docid{get;set;}
public string filename{get; set;}
public string doctype{get;set;}
}
```

so, each key in the dictionary has a list of values. 
I want to write the values for all the keys in a csv file.

My csv file will have columns of

- docid
- filename
- doctype

I have been using LINQ2CSV library for writing into csv, but since it accepts a list and a filepath as a parameter, i am not able to collect values for all the keys into a list.
please suggest a better way to achieve this .

Comment: Btw, if every key in the dictionary has  a "list of values" it would be a `Dictionary<string, List<Data>>` instead.

Comment: Data is pretty broad could be a list too.

Comment: @JoachimGotzes: but it contains only those three properties.

Comment: @TimSchmelter No what i meant was that Data = List<something>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ2CSV's `Write` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>`. Your [`Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in dictionary are available as an array. You can do:

```
cc.Write(yourDictionary.Values, "filePath.csv");
```

There is no need for getting `List<Data>` from Dictionary `Values`, but if you still want to create a `List<Data>` you can do:

```
List<Data> myList = yourDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

or

```
List<Data> myList = new List<Data>(yourDicitionary.Values);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the values of your dictionary to a list:

```
var list = dictionary.Values.ToList();
```